# PHP сравнение строк

Tags: php, преобразование-типов

Ребята, почему перечисленные условия возвращают true?

```
var_dump("10" == "1e1"); //true
var_dump(100 == "1e2"); //true
var_dump("1" == "01"); //true
```

Спасибо

Comment: Если сравнивать теплое с красным эфект будет таким же как в примере, для сравнения строк есть `strcmp`, для сравнения включая типы есть `===`.

Comment: Владимир, а если по существу? Вопрос ведь не в том, как сравнивать типы, а в том, почему строка "10" равна "1e1"

Comment: А если по существу я вам ответил, вы сравниваете **теплое с красным** и хотите верного результата, сравнение строк - `strcmp` то что делаете вы - не является сравнением для строк, и может преобразовать их неявно к другому типу и провести сравнение по другому типу. В ответе ниже разжевали конкретно ваш случай, но с такими фокусами вы будете часто сталкиваться пока не поймете что `==` - не для строк.

Answer (score 4):

Если строка распознается как числовое значение, результирующее значение и тип определяется так, как показано далее.

К примеру:

`100 == "1e2"` - true, так как 1 умножить на 10 в квадрате равно 100.

Аналогично, `1e1` это 1 умножить на 10 в первой степени, значит ровно 10. Такая запись удобна для записи очень больших или очень маленьких чисел. Например, `6.02e23` - это [число Авогадро](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE), которое без экспоненциальной записи будет иметь вид что-то вроде 602214076000000000000000.

> Если строка не содержит какой-либо из символов '.', 'e', или 'E', и
>   значение числа помещается в пределы целых чисел (определенных
>   PHP_INT_MAX), строка будет распознана как целое число
>   Во всех остальных случаях она считается числом с плавающей точкой (float).
>
> Значение определяется по начальной части строки. Если строка
>   начинается с верного числового значения, будет использовано это
>   значение. Иначе значением будет 0 (ноль). Верное числовое значение -
>   это одна или более цифр (могущих содержать десятичную точку), по
>   желанию предваренных знаком с последующим необязательным показателем
>   степени. Показатель степени - это 'e' или 'E' с последующими одной или
>   более цифрами.

Это все описано [в этой статье из мануала по PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion).

Про [экспоненциальную запись чисел вообще](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C).

Comment: подскажите, где можно почитать про значение символов в строке "1e2" ?

Comment: @Eaunemo в [википедии например](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)